# Recursive function dies with Memory Error

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

Say we have a function that translates the morse symbols:

- `.` -> `-.`
- `-` -> `...-`

If we apply this function twice, we get e.g:

`.` -> `-.` -> `...--.`

Given an input string and a number of repetitions,  want to know the length of the final string. (Problem 1 from the [Flemish Programming Contest](http://www.vlaamseprogrammeerwedstrijd.be/current/) VPW, taken from [these slides](http://users.ugent.be/~tschrijv/Research/talks/fpg_5_2012.pdf) which provide a solution in Haskell).

For the given inputfile

```
4
. 4
.- 2
-- 2 
--... 50
```

We expect the solution

```
44
16
20
34028664377246354505728
```

Since I don't know Haskell, this is my recursive solution in Python that I came up with:

```
def encode(msg, repetition, morse={'.': '-.', '-': '...-'}):
    if isinstance(repetition, str):
        repetition = eval(repetition)
    while repetition > 0:
        newmsg = ''.join(morse[c] for c in msg)
        return encode(newmsg, repetition-1)
    return len(msg)


def problem1(fn):
    with open(fn) as f:
        f.next()
        for line in f:
            print encode(*line.split())
```

which works for the first three inputs but dies with a memory error for the last input.

How would you rewrite this in a more efficient way?

**Edit**

Rewrite based on the comments given:

```
def encode(p, s, repetition):
    while repetition > 0:
        p,s = p + 3*s, p + s
        return encode(p, s, repetition-1)
    return p + s


def problem1(fn):
    with open(fn) as f:
        f.next()
        for line in f:
            msg, repetition = line.split()
            print encode(msg.count('.'), msg.count('-'), int(repetition))
```

Comments on style and further improvements still welcome

Comment: Convert it to a while loop.  You are hitting recursion limits, basically, so if you remove the recursion, your problem should go away.

Comment: @sr2222: No, recursion limits are a `RuntimeError`. It's a memory limit, because the questioner is trying to create a huge string.

Comment: @ThomasK There're certainly non-trivial memory overhead concerns with n-depth recursion too though.

Comment: @ThomasK is exactly right- you have to solve the problem without actually creating this string. It would take up a total of *34 trillion gigabytes*. Even without any recursive overhead this would break.

Comment: As a comparison, just for fun- the string would take up 34 million petabytes. The Blue Waters Supercomputer being built by Cray, which will be the largest storage array of all time, will hold 500 petabytes.

Comment: Quite so.  Hence why DGH has the right answer.  :)

Comment: do not ever use eval anywhere. Use int for decoding the repetition!

Comment: By the way, the solutions outlined so far all have linear complexity in the number of repetitions. There is a more efficient solution using matrix exponentiation by squaring which will allow you to solve this efficiently for very large numbers of repetitions. It's a good exercise for when you've gotten this to work :)

Comment: @hammar: I have gotten it to work, see my edit. So if you could expand on your 'matrix exponentiation by squaring' solution I would be very interested.

Comment: @BioGeek: You can write the update `p, s = p + 3*s, p + s` as the product of the 2x2 matrix `A = [[1, 3], [1, 1]]` by the column vector `[p, s]`. Now, instead of multiplying the matrix by the vector `n` times (_O(n)_ matrix-vector multiplications), you can compute the matrix `A^n` efficiently using  exponentiation by squaring (_O(log n)_ matrix-matrix multiplications), and then multiply that by `[p, s]` to get the counts after `n` steps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider that you don't actually have to output the resulting string, only the length of it. Also consider that the order of '.' and '-' in the string do not affect the final length (e.g. ".- 3" and "-. 3" produce the same final length).

Thus, I would give up on storing the entire string and instead store the number of '.' and the number of '-' as integers.

Comment: Also consider that a string of 34028664377246354505728 characters is 21 Zettabytes.

Comment: If you read the slides, this is exactly what the Haskell solution does.

Comment: @ThomasK- why 21 rather than 34 (or 30 if you're using a binary prefix)?

Comment: @DavidRobinson: I was using a binary prefix, but I made a typo. It's 29. (Technically then they're Zebibytes, but I've never heard anyone use *bibytes in real discussion)

Answer (score 2):

In your starting string, count the number of dots and dashes. Then apply this:

```
repetitions = 4
dots = 1
dashes = 0
for i in range(repetitions):
    dots, dashes = dots + 3 * dashes, dashes + dots
```

Think about it why this works.

Answer (score 2):

Per @Hammar (I had the same idea, but he explained it better than I could have ;-):

```
from sympy import Matrix

t = Matrix([[1,3],[1,1]])

def encode(dots, dashes, reps):
    res = matrix([dashes, dots]) * t**reps
    return res[0,0] + res[0,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

you put the count of dots to dashes, and count of dashes to dots in each iteration...

```
def encode(dots, dashes, repetitions):
    while repetitions > 0:
        dots, dashes = dots + 3 * dashes, dots + dashes
        repetitions -= 1

    return dots + dashes

def problem1(fn):
    with open(fn) as f:
        count = int(next(f))
        for i in xrange(count):
            line = next(f)
            msg, repetition = line.strip().split()
            print encode(msg.count('.'), msg.count('-'), int(repetition))
```